# How to fetch data from multiple cell to a single cell one value at a time?

Tags: excel

I am entering data into an excel sheet (Say SHEET1) on a daily basis. Each day I enter values to respective cells. For example:

**SHEET 1**

```
Row1---> Day 1 -    value1

Row2---> Day 2 -    value2

Row3---> Day 3 -    value3

Row4---> Day 4 -    value4

Row5---> Day 5 -    value5
```

I want to reflect the value in sheet (Say SHEET2). For example:

**SHEET 2**

```
CellX = <<<<"Value From SHEET1">>>>
```

I want the data from SHEET1 to reflect in CellX in SHEET2. The value of cell X needs to get replaced every time I enter a new value.

For example: If on Day 1 I enter a value in SHEET1, 1st row, it should get reflected in CellX.

Now while I am entering the second value that is Day 2, CellX in SHEET2 needs to get replaced by the Day 2 value.

How do I do that?
Kindly suggest me solutions.

Comment: You can combine OFFSET() and COUNTA() to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

In **Sheet1** then in cell **B2** of **Sheet2** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(99^99,Sheet1!B:B)
```

to get the last entered value in column **B** of that first sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. that solved my problem. One more question what if i want to skip number of rows (say 2 rows) and fetch the value last entered.

Comment: Thank you.. that solved my problem. One more question what if i want to skip number of rows (say 2 rows) and fetch the value last entered. For example, i want the value from 1st row, then from 4th row (Skip 2 rows), then from 7th row (skip 2 rows) and continue like that.

Comment: That can be achieved with a simple **INDEX()** function

Comment: Can you expalin how to do it or can you show me the formula?

Comment: Its like retrieving the Last entered + nth value = Display in a single cell. I have tried different combinations, but nothing is working.